# How to check if a file exists in Java without blocking?

Tags: java

If calling `new File(path).exists()` a call to the file system is generally needed, so in my understanding this is not an appropriate call to make from a single-threaded event loop. All the nio-based file classes such as `AsynchronousFileChannel` appear to do non-blocking reads or writes, but checking for the existence of the file appears to be blocking. Is there a way to check a file exists, and/or get metadata such as file size in a non-blocking fashion?

Comment: Why would an existence check or getting a file's size require opening the file?

Comment: You can write a thread that monitors changes in a directory and access the data maintained by it if even a directory read isn't tolerable.

Comment: Why isn't? If it's done outside of the Netty IO thread I think it's perfectly OK.

Comment: There isn't, in general, even a way to do this from lower-level languages (although it's OS dependent of course). So, no, there's no way to do it from Java (other than spawning a separate dedicated thread).

Comment: It appears to be blocking or it is blocking? Why use `File(path).exists()` and not `java.nio.file.Files#exists(Path, LinkOptions)` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-)?

Comment: `java.nio.file.Files#exists(Path, LinkOptions)` returns a boolean, rather than some kind of future, so I think that means it's blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from @davmac the answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 0):

> so in my understanding this is not an appropriate call to make from a single-threaded event loop such as in Netty.

Your understanding is not correct, and this is a *non sequitur.*

> All the nio-based file classes such as FileChannel appear to do non-blocking reads or writes

That's not correct either. `FileChannel` does not perform non-blocking I/O.

> but opening the file appears to be blocking.

You will havrno explain how you arrive at that conclusion and how it is adversely affecting you.

> Is there a way to check a file exists, and/or get metadata such as file size in a non-blocking fashion?

There are several ways to check for file existence in Java, such as `File.exists()`, whatever the corresponding method in`Files` is, and simply trying to open it and catching the `FileNotFoundException` that results if it doesn't.

**None** of them blocks, at least not for any appreciable amount of time

Comment: "None of them blocks" on what basis do you make this claim? I would fully expect that checking for the existence of a file might require reading from the disk where the file resides (and which the directory structure itself is stored on).

Comment: @davmac None of them blocks for any appreciable amount of time.

Comment: that's not the same thing as not blocking at all, though. (What if the file is on slow media? What if it's on a network which is currently slow or down?)

Comment: Can you explain why it's okay to call `Files.exists()` in a single-threaded event loop? As @davmac points out if the lookup is slow, e.g. 10ms, it would block every request on the whole server for 10ms. (And when I said "opening the file" I meant to say that just checking for its existence on disk.)

Comment: I updated the question to refer to `AsynchronousFileChannel` which has non-blocking operations. I came to the conclusion that checking for file existence is blocking by observing that it returns a boolean (rather than a future or similar) and yet IO is required in the common case. So the answer is to not check for file existence in a single-threaded event loop.

Comment: @EJP "None of them blocks" - what if file is on mounted remote file system eg NFS or via FUSE and there is connectivity problem? it will definitely block